# Uniform Probability Measure on a Finitely Generated Group

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

I am working through a proof. Here's the setup: $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated group with finite symmetric generating set $S \subset \Gamma$. In this proof the author takes an arbitrary "uniform probability measure $\mu$ on $S$." First, how does one construct this measure $\mu$? And does it extend to all of $\Gamma$? I think when he says "on $S$", the author means that the support of $\mu$ is $S$. But I'm not entirely certain. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5431.pdf) is a link to the paper (see the first corollary for more details).

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a big difference between saying a (uniform probability) measure is defined on $S$ or has support on $S$ in this context and it looks like they interchange as they use the language you suggest in the first paragraph.

To construct the measure define $\mu(\{x\})= \frac{1}{|S|}$ if $x \in S$ and $0$ otherwise.